# Android, should I center content?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm pretty new to android and wanted to ask about the centering practices, what I mean is that for example:

Before I say something, I don't know what are the good practices are so...

I can have a `LinearLayout` with height as `match_parent` and `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`(btw, according to [google's material](https://material.google.com/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing) `56dp`).

So that is one option, **but**, I saw apps where the content is centered nicely if the device is really long(such as Galaxy Note devices), so what I did is:

Same `LinearLayout` but with height as `wrap_content` and `android:layout_gravity="center"`, **but** the problem here is with for example a form with 1 field(almost no content height), the problem is that almost no content will leave you with a lot of space between the toolbar and the content and below that content as well.

**My question:** altought may be obscure I'm asking for the best practices, what is the best approach that will make content(bigger or smaller) appear nicly on multiple devices, maybe it would require multiple layouts/dimens, I'm ok with that, just looking for the right path.

Comment: You can get started with [Google Material Design](https://material.google.com/) and [Android Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/index.html). `:)`

Comment: what about `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: @MaskedMan I'm looking for specific solution for specific problem, I will read them but that takes time.

Comment: @MohammadZ can you explain more, maybe an answer with example?

Comment: @AvielFedida, I know my suggestion is time consuming but your question is either! There's not a definitive answer to your question and you should spend some time examining the options. `:)`

Comment: @AvielFedida yeah, sure....

Comment: If you give me a picture of your desire layout...maybe I can help you better

Answer (score 1):

There is another view group named `RelativeLayout`.

You can use it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        // here you can use attributes such as `android:layout_below`, `android:layout_above`,`layout_toRightOf`
        //to modify and control your items
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which asked about "best practices" or reasons that centered content would be best. Not *how to center*